# python string replacement using tuple values

Tags: python

This code will return the text that I am looking for. But I am not able to adjust the punctuation marks.

```
fieldnames = ("user","messageid","message","destination", "code","mobile","mytimestamp")
newData = ["\'%s\': %s" % (tup, tup) for tup in fieldnames if tup!='destination' ]
```

newData will return

```
["'user': user", "'messageid': messageid", "'message': message", "'code': code", "'mobile': mobile",  "'mytimestamp': mytimestamp"]
```

I need to remove the double quotes and add \

The expected string (not list) output is this...

```
"[\'user\': user, \'messageid\': messageid, \'message\': message, \'code\': code, \'mobile\': mobile, \'mytimestamp\': mytimestamp]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
fieldnames = ("user","messageid","message","destination", "code","mobile","mytimestamp")

s = "[%s]" % ', '.join(["\\'%s\\': %s" % (t,t) for t in fieldnames if t != 'destination'])
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have it almost done. You only need these minor changes:

1. Use raw strings, just add an `r` before the string you already have:

   `r"\'%s\': %s"`
2. You have a list with all the string groups you need. Just join them using `str.join`:

   `', '.join(newData)`
3. The only thing missing are your opening and closing brackets.

Your whole code would be:

```
fieldnames = ("user","messageid","message","destination", "code","mobile","mytimestamp")
newData = [r"\'%s\': %s" % (tup, tup) for tup in fieldnames if tup!='destination' ]

print('[' + ', '.join(newData) + ']')
# [\'user\': user, \'messageid\': messageid, \'message\': message, \'code\': code, \'mobile\': mobile, \'mytimestamp\': mytimestamp]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code to something like

```
newData = ("\"[" +
           ", ".join("\\'%s\\': %s" % (tup, tup)
                     for tup in fieldnames if  tup!='destination') +
           "]\"")
```

Note: I am assuming you want the double quotes, backslash and single quotes being part of the string. For sure the output is neither Python nor Javascript as `:` is used for dictionaries/objects but they require braces `{`/`}` and not brackets `[`/`]`.